# BigSQL PostgreSQL CREATE EXTENSION errors

Tags: postgresql, dll, postgresql-9.5, postgres-fdw, bigsql

I have windows 8.1 and I want to try hadoop_fdw. Problem is with loading the extension with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hadoop_fdw;
```

ddssdg

```
ERROR:  could not load library "D:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~2/pg95/../pg95/lib/postgresql/hadoop_fdw.dll": unknown error 126
********** Error **********
ERROR: could not load library "D:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~2/pg95/../pg95/lib/postgresql/hadoop_fdw.dll": unknown error 126
SQL state: XX000
```

I tried to create extension manually from SQL located at "D:\Program Files\PostgreSQLBigsql\pg95\share\postgresql\extension"

```
CREATE FUNCTION hadoop_fdw_handler()
RETURNS fdw_handler
AS 'D:\Program Files\PostgreSQLBigsql\pg95\lib\postgresql\hadoop_fdw.dll'
LANGUAGE C STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION hadoop_fdw_validator(text[], oid)
RETURNS void
AS 'D:\Program Files\PostgreSQLBigsql\pg95\lib\postgresql\hadoop_fdw.dll'
LANGUAGE C STRICT;

CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER hadoop_fdw
  HANDLER hadoop_fdw_handler
  VALIDATOR hadoop_fdw_validator;
```

I get this error same error again:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "D:\Program Files\PostgreSQLBigsql\pg95\lib\postgresql\hadoop_fdw.dll": unknown error 126
********** Error **********

ERROR: could not load library "D:\Program Files\PostgreSQLBigsql\pg95\lib\postgresql\hadoop_fdw.dll": unknown error 126
SQL state: XX000
```

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT 1:** So I found missing DLL's. They are:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
JVM.DLL
```

I added them to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ and extension still doesn't work - it probably requires restart.

Comment: Maybe a 32bit vs. 64bit problem? Or maybe hadoop_fdw.dll tries to load other DLLs that are not available. I usually hunt down things like that using [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/340-Foreign-Data-Wrappers-for-PostgreSQL-9.4-Windows.html

Comment: I tried other extensions, CassandraFDW is OK, but OraFDW ends with same error http://bigsql.org/docs/